# Three term singular perturbation expansion

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm looking to find the first three terms in the perturbation expansion for all three roots of the equation

$x^3+x^2-\epsilon=0$, where  $0<\epsilon \ll 1 $.

So far, by setting $x=x_0+\epsilon^\alpha x_1+ \epsilon^{2\alpha} x_2$ and equating terms of equal order, I've been able to find one root - $x_0=-1,  x_1=-1,x_2=2$ and this is with $\alpha =1 $.

Could anyone help find the other two. I've tired equating higher order terms with no success. Also, when I let $y=\frac{x}{\delta}$ and get $\delta=\epsilon^{\frac{1}{3}}$, I'm still not getting anywhere after.

Thanks.

Comment: What you found is that the root near $-1$ is a regular perturbation problem, so you should indeed expect the series to be in integer powers of $\epsilon$. The derivative at $-1$ is $1$, which is positive, so indeed the coefficient in the first correction term should be negative as you found. So that looks reasonable. Now, the root near $0$ is a singular perturbation problem: you should expect the root to be split into two, and since $x^2$ is the dominant term there, you should expect to see a series in half-integer powers of $\epsilon$.

Comment: You should find that by doing dominant balance: if $x=\delta y$ then $\delta^3 y^3+\delta^2 y^2-\epsilon=0$. If $y$ is order $1$ then the second term dominates over the first so the second and third terms will need to balance. This can only happen if $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$, so to leading order the equation reads $\epsilon y^2-\epsilon=0$ so that $y=\pm 1$ to leading order. Now you need to work out corrections.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So now, setting $y=\frac{x}{\delta}$ and $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$, must I just solve $y^3 \epsilon^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^2 \epsilon -\epsilon =0$?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, but now that's a perturbation problem unto itself.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by - work out the corrections?

Comment: As I said, to leading order, $y=\pm 1$ so $x=\pm \sqrt{\epsilon}$. But you need three terms. So you need to find two more terms.

Comment: When you set $\delta=\epsilon^{1/3}$, it didn't work because your equation was $\epsilon y^3+\epsilon^{2/3}y^2-\epsilon=0$, but $\epsilon^{2/3}\gg\epsilon$, so you don't have a *dominant balance*. That is why you have to pick $\delta=\epsilon^{1/2}$.